# Navbar Missing from Razor Pages Application after Publishing to Azure App Service

Tags: razor, navbar, azure-appservice

I have a razor pages application, I'm using mostly default things, but I am in fact using Blazorise components as well. When I launch the app from Visual Studio everything operates perfect. However, when I publish the application to Azure the app loads but it's only showing me the razor component that is the @page "/" file but NOT the MainLayout. In this case the NavBar on the side and the Top bar are completely missing. I've searched and searched but haven't found anything helpful. It's using .Net 7.0 . App.Razor is unmodified.

Here is my _Host.cshtml page

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css">

    <link href="_content/Blazorise/blazorise.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/Blazorise.Bootstrap5/blazorise.bootstrap5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/Blazorise.LoadingIndicator/blazorise.loadingindicator.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/Blazorise.Snackbar/blazorise.snackbar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="AppName.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Here is the F12 output for the page that isn't displaying properly with the relevant pieces extracted:

```
<div class="page" b-i2o9dhowsh=""><div class="sidebar" b-i2o9dhowsh=""><!--!--><div class="top-row ps-3 navbar navbar-dark" b-lbf1yz0eya=""><div class="container-fluid" b-lbf1yz0eya=""><!--!--><a class="navbar-brand" href="" b-lbf1yz0eya="">MTT Video Files</a>
        <button title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler" b-lbf1yz0eya=""><!--!--><span class="navbar-toggler-icon" b-lbf1yz0eya=""></span></button></div></div><!--!-->

<div class="collapse nav-scrollable" b-lbf1yz0eya=""><nav class="flex-column" b-lbf1yz0eya=""><div class="nav-item px-3" b-lbf1yz0eya=""><!--!--><a href="" class="nav-link active"><!--!--><span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true" b-lbf1yz0eya=""></span> Home
            </a></div><!--!-->
        <div class="nav-item px-3" b-lbf1yz0eya=""><!--!--><a href="fileuploads" class="nav-link"><!--!--><span class="oi oi-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true" b-lbf1yz0eya=""></span> File Upload
            </a></div><!--!-->
        <div class="nav-item px-3" b-lbf1yz0eya=""><!--!--><a href="files" class="nav-link"><!--!--><span class="oi oi-cloud" aria-hidden="true" b-lbf1yz0eya=""></span> Files Management
            </a></div><!--!-->
        <div class="nav-item px-3" b-lbf1yz0eya=""><!--!--><a href="translate" class="nav-link"><!--!--><span class="oi oi-globe" aria-hidden="true" b-lbf1yz0eya=""></span> Translate Documents
            </a></div><!--!-->
        <div class="nav-item px-3" b-lbf1yz0eya=""><!--!--><a href="translatestatus" class="nav-link"><!--!--><span class="oi oi-task" aria-hidden="true" b-lbf1yz0eya=""></span> Translation Status
            </a></div></nav></div></div><!--!-->

    <main b-i2o9dhowsh=""><!--!--><div class="top-row px-4" b-i2o9dhowsh=""><a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank" b-i2o9dhowsh="">About</a></div>

        <article class="content px-4" b-i2o9dhowsh=""><!--!--><!--!--><!--!--><!--!-->

<!--!--><h1 tabindex="-1">Application</h1>

<br>
<br>

<br>

<!--!--><h3>Use the navigation bar to do the following</h3>
<br>
<!--!--><a href="fileuploads">Upload files </a>
<br>
<!--!--><a href="files">Manage Files (including downloads)</a>
<br>
<!--!--><a href="translate">Translate Existing documents</a></article></main></div>
```

Happy to share more, but not sure what you would want to see :) Any help is GREATLY appreciated as this one has me stumped.

I've tried to rebuild, clean, republish multiple times.

UPDATE - I "figured out" the problem, but I still don't know why. At build time, the application generates a file called App.styles.css in the root of the wwwroot directory. This is because of [CSS Isolation] [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and is by design. The issue is that it generates these random class structure identifiers with a b- in the name. That b- value reference in the HTML section (see above where it says b-lbf1yz0eya) was not correct. The App.style.css file in my local dev environment had the correct name. So to fix it, I used the Kudu console and replaced the contents of the file in the Azure App Service with the contents that were in my local dev copy and BOOM everything is working again...Probably won't persist between updates but at least I know...

Comment: I think I am having a similar problem to yours. I published my Blazor Server application to IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012. Can you please elaborate how you fixed your issue?